# Defining an arraylist and putting the resultset data into,and looing through the arraylist

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, duplicates, resultset

I need to print two ResultSets on the jsp page based on certain conditions.
i declared an arraylist of the fields,wrote their getter and setter methods.
i declared an arraylist of this class on the jsp.i added the resultset into the arraylist,now i dont know how to loop through the arraylist and check for duplicates for printing the second resultset.please help!

Comment: i can not understand this `check for duplicates for printing the second resultset`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the loop using your arrayList object size method.Now here for each datalist it will fetch into the class below:-

```
for (Class cls : dataList)
{
//compare here hashcode 
  //cls.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: i have declared the arraylist as ArrayList<TableRow> dataList=new ArrayList<TableRow>();where TableRow is the class of the feilds of resultset with thier egtters and setters

Comment: Yes i have added the resultset into the arraylist

Comment: I have modified your code. Compare using hashcode your previous element and next element to avoid duplicates

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the objects and not the index:

```
for(TableRow tr : dataList) {
    // Some code
}
```

Comment: and how do i check for duplicates and print the second resultset containing the same data but without duplicates

Comment: By duplicate, do you mean the same Object? or that are equal by comparing them with a function like equals(...)

Comment: by duplicates i mean,the same rows that will printed in the table of first resultset and second resultset